# Optimization TSQL with R

Tags: sql-server, r, t-sql, ssms

We're using TSQL with R on Microsoft SQL Server 2016 in a project.

The problem is the execution time, the usage of R or the connection take a random time between 200ms and 600ms.

I think it's a configuration problem but I've never used this before.

Example of request:

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script    
      @language = N'R'    
    , @script = N' 
         OutputDataSet <- as.data.frame(rnorm(100, mean = 50, sd =3));'    
    , @input_data_1 = N'   ;'    
      WITH RESULT SETS (([Density] float NOT NULL));
```

Execute time this take between 200ms and 2000ms.

If anyone have already used this kind of technology and have some tips to optimize the performance?

N.B : In our project we're using this kind of request dynamically so, there's a lot of request executed and we're waiting all results to display them. It take a lot of time. I hope it's jsut a configuration of ssms problem

Answer (score 0):

The execution time for R scripts can vary depending on whether an R process is already available for script execution or not. You can validate this by looking for running Rterm.exe processes using Task Manager (or Process Explorer).

[image]

So the behavior you will notice is that first request may be slow (~2000ms) and the subsequent requests will be faster (~200ms).

Comment: As seen above, R scripts runs outside of SQL Server process. Due to overhead to send data between processes and additional R interpreter execution time, it is not feasible to have the same performance as native SQL. 

Can you explain your scenario and requirement for ~10-40ms briefly? Is your R scripts doing predictions or other kind of data analysis?

Comment: We're just creating dynamically the R scripts depending of a lot of parameters and using some native function of R for some calculation.
Apparently, it's not the good usage, we expect use this as a api service but the perf are too bad for this